# How to import part of a module in python?

Tags: python, module, import

I need to use a python module (available in some library). The module looks like this:

```
class A:
  def f1():
  ...

print "Done"
...
```

I need only the functionality of class A. However, when I import the module, the code at bottom (print and others) gets executed. Is there a way to avoid that? Essentially I need to import part of a module: "from module1 import A" which should import only A. Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, sure:

```
from module1 import A
```

Is the general syntax. For example:

```
from datetime import timedelta
```

The code at the bottom should be protected from running at import time by being wrapped like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Put code that should only run when the module
  # is used as a stand-alone program, here.
  # It will not run when the module is imported.
```

Comment: The problem is its an existing module and code at bottom is not protected as you mentioned.

Comment: This is of course importing the whole module in the background but just puts part of it in the namespace. E.g. if `module1.A` depends on nothing but `module1.B` depends on `werkzeug`, this will still require `werkzeug` installed.

Comment: Or, to rename something as you import it: `from module1 import A as B`

Answer (score 3):

If you're only annoyed by the print statements, you could redirect the code's output to somewhere invisible, like explained in one comment of this post: http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2009/05/python-redirect-or-turn-off-stdout-and.html

```
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
# now doing the stuff you need
...

# but do not forget to come back!
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdin

But if you want to deactivate file modifications, or time-consuming code, the only thing that comes to my mind is some dirty trick: copy the objects you need in another file, then import it (but I do not recommend it!).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@unwind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283876/how-to-import-part-of-a-module-in-python/4283887#4283887) the usual way of doing this is to protect the code in the module that should only be run if the module is used directly with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    <code to only execute if module called directly>
```

That way you can import the module normally.

Comment: If you don't have control over the module, so that you can't make it look like this, you're SOL.  do this always.